# DiscordJS: How to check if user is in voice chat (For a XP system)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently developing a discord bot, and I made an Leveling system where users get XP as they talk in chat, pretty simple, but I would like some help to know if I can keep track of how much time a user has spent in a Voice Chat, so I could give him XP for being in a VoiceChat.

Example of what I wanted to do:

`if (userIsInVoiceChat) {setInterval(() => { giveUser.xp}, 30000)`

So basically every 30 seconds while the user is in a VC he would get XP, I would like to know if that is possible, plus some code would be very helpful xD

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
if(member.voice.channel) { /* do code thing stuff */}
```